# Mandelbrot precision target the center of a pixel?

Tags: fractals

I read this question and I don't understand the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8381675/how-to-perform-simple-zoom-into-mandelbrot-set?rq=1. Especially how can I aim for the center of the pixel like so:

```
  for(unsigned SX = SMin; x < SMax; ++x) {
     double k = (double(SX + 0.5) - SMin) / (SMax - SMin);
     double IX = (k * (IMax - IMin)) + IMin;
  }
```

Is k then the real factor and ix the imaginary factor?

I've made an example here: http://www.phpdevpad.de/index.php?id=190 but how can I find the corner pixel when I want to zoom into it like so:

```
 double Re_factor = (MaxRe-MinRe)/(ImageWidth-1);
 double Im_factor = (MaxIm-MinIm)/(ImageHeight-1);
 double newMinRe = MinRe + (Re_factor* x1);
 double newMaxRe = MinRe + (Re_factor* x2);
 double newMinIm = MinIm + (Im_factor* y1);
 double newMaxIm = MinIm + (Im_factor* y2);
```

In my example the zoomed image is a bit tall in the y-axis. Why is this?

Update: IX is the x-value in the imaginary space hence my first question is answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use Im_factor = Re_factor (assuming square pixels on your screen).
In other words, $(MaxRe-MinRe):(MaxIm-MinIm)$ should equal $(ImageWidth-1):(ImageHeight-1)$.

Comment: Do you mean 16:10? How would I do this? Because the default mandelbrot image seems to work and I use exactly the same real and imaginary steps with the formula in the linked post?

Comment: Thank you. That seems to work. But how can zoom out the area?